# Google map API v3: YoutTube videos are not played in infowindow. I get a blank window instead?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, youtube-api, infowindow

I am trying to put youtube videos inside infowindows, but it is not working. I get only empty windows.

Here is my code. Since it is my first Javascript project, I am sure that I am doing something wrong. Can you please help me find where the problem is?

I tried it on Chrome and Firefox.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>


  <script>
  function initMap(){
    // Map options
    var centerCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(52.2799, 8.0472);
    var options = {
      zoom:8,
      center:centerCoords,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN    // satellite, hybrid, terrain, roadmap
    }

    // New map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

    // Listen for click on map
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
      // Add marker
      addMarker({coords:event.latLng});
    });

    // Array of markers
    var markers = [
      {
        coords: new google.maps.LatLng(52.2799, 8.0472),
        //content:'<h1> Osnabrueck </h1>',
        url: getYoutubeId('https://www.youtube.com/r6UbYB5yMX8'),
        //iconImage:'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
      }  
    ];


    var any_window =false;
    for(var i = 0;i < markers.length;i++){
      // Add marker
      addMarker(markers[i], any_window);
    }

    function addMarker(props, any_window){
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:props.coords,
        map:map,
        //icon:props.iconImage
      });

      // Check for customicon
      if(props.iconImage){
        // Set icon image
        marker.setIcon(props.iconImage);
      }

      // Check content
      if(props.url){
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          embed_url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + props.url,
          content: '<video controls="" style="height:350px; width:600px;><iframe title="YouTube video player">'
           + '<type="text/html" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" src=embed_url frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></video>'

        });

        marker.addListener('click', function(){  //click, mouseover, mouseout
          if (!any_window){
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            any_window = true;
          }
        });

      } // end if props.content
    } //addMarker

//################ get youtube id function ######################
    function getYoutubeId(url){
      var videoid = url.match(/(?:https?:\/{2})?(?:w{3}\.)?youtu(?:be)?\.(?:com|be)(?:\/watch\?v=|\/)([^\s&]+)/);
      if(videoid == null) {
        console.log(url + " is not a valid YouTube url");
      }
        return videoid[1];
      };
//###############################################################

  } //initMap
  </script>
  <!--  ###########################################################  -->

  <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=***API_KEY***&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Providing a working code snippet might be a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this code:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    embed_url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + props.url,
    content: '<video controls="" style="height:350px; width:600px;><iframe title="YouTube video player">'
       + '<type="text/html" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" src=embed_url frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></video>'

});
```

to:

```
var embed_url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + props.url;
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<iframe title="YouTube video player" type="text/html" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" src=' + embed_url + ' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
});
```

I made `embed_url` a variable rather than an property of the InfoWindowOptions object. Then I use string concatenation to add its value to the InfoWindow content: `src=' + embed_url + '`.

This only fixes the InfoWindow for the marker that is initially on the map.

You'll have to revise your code in order to get videos to load for the other markers you create when you click on the map.

Comment: thanks a lot. that was what I needed. I do not need to change the code since the user-added markers are not suppose to have a video.

Comment: Awesome! No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: Google map update Policy your example not work